# How can I open PuTTY's Window Control Menu (Alt+Space) using the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, putty

While working with PuTTY in an SSH session, I'd like to use the [Window Control Menu](https://documentation.help/PuTTY/using-sysmenu.html) by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, like in other Windows, but this shortcut doesn't work, as it seems that PuTTY is capturing and sending it to the remote system.

Is there a setting or an alternative way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PuTTY Configuration window, go to:
*Window > Behaviour > System menu appears on ALT-Space*

See [https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-altspace](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-altspace)

Comment: I swear I looked for this option up and down over many weeks and my eyes seem to have always skipped seeing it. Thank you very much for making my life easier.